# Options method doesn't contain 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header - Django Rest Framework

Tags: azure, django-rest-framework, cors, azure-api-management, django-cors-headers

I have created some GET APIs which are deployed as an app in Azure. I have linked the same to Azure API Management and added the APIs definitions there.

When I am trying to hit the APIs from the API Management Developer Portal I am getting CORS issue.

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
> the remote resource at `my_http_url_here`. (Reason: CORS header
> ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 200.

I tracked the `OPTIONS` request, it doesn't include the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in response.

[image]

I have also created one separate request corresponding to `OPTIONS` to verify and when it is triggered I do get the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`

[image]

I am not able to understand what additional setting am I missing. Any ideas?

I have already added `ALLOWED_HOSTS` and `CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS` but still it's giving the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your azure app service portal and set the cors origin to either * or the client domain

1. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40NlH.png)

2.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2mtc.png)

Comment: I have entered those earlier but with that too it didn't work. I had to create another Developer Portal to overcome this. I am not sure where was the issue but guess I might have missed some config earlier. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).